# d3: Zoom to Bounding Box II for countries instead of states

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I'm trying to get the d3 Zoom to Bounding Box II example (see here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/9656675/) working for a world map rather than the US states map as per the example.  Unfortunately the zooming is erratic. For some countries it works fine; for others it zooms way off into the Pacific Ocean.

I'd JSFiddle my code by I can't load the topojson file from a remote location.  The relevant function I edited in the above example is below:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator() // instead of albersUsa
    .scale(100)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

d3.json("world-110m.json", function(error, world) { //world json
  if (error) throw error;

  g.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features) //traverse world objects instead of state objects
    .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("class", "feature")
  .on("click", clicked);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })) // append world objects not states
      .attr("class", "mesh")
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

Any help appreciated.

NOTE: I just realized that the zoom is erratic for some states as well.  Try clicking on VT or NH, for example. I'll file a bug on GitHub.  Meanwhile any ideas?

Comment: Could it come from your version of "world-110m.json"?
I recreated your map here with my version of the world json, and it seems to be working well. Any specific country you had a problem with?

     http://plnkr.co/edit/L4U1fRXq9wre1DrigkLJ?p=preview

You can download the world map from the plunk.

Comment: were you able to solve that?

Comment: I should have updated sooner.  I posted an issue on Git and Mike Bostock issued a fix within hours: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2819.  Turns out I was running an (slightly) out-of-date version of d3.  That and he modified the scale in the bounds var.  See his response at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I assume answering my own question (even if I wasn't the one who solved it) is kosher.

Mike Bostock said I was running a slightly out-of-date version of d3.  Run at least D3 3.5.7 and then update the bounds var:

`scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height)))`

He fixed the examples on his site, too.